# Invert scrolling direction HorizontalScrollview

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

On default if you swipe from left to right you scroll to the left, and vice versa.

But I want to invert this action. so if you swipe left to right the scrollview goes to the right. Is there a XML solution or do I have to do this in code?

Comment: Curious as to why you would want that? It's very unintuitive.

Comment: I have 1 scrollview that contains a set of images next to each other that the user can scroll through, this scrolls like a normal scrollview. The other scrollview that needs to be inverted is like a overview of all the images but then smaller so that it fits on the screen so the user can navigate faster when there is a large set of images. these scrollviews move in sync. I'm still finding out what is the best possible way to tackle this situation. So I will try the current answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty unsure about this but something along these lines:

1. Intercept touch event
2. Invert the X positions
3. Dispatch the new inverted touch event

Code (not really):

```
HorizontalScrollView hsv;
hsv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        event.setLocation(-1*event.getX(), event.getY());
        hsv.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GestureDetector to listen for left/right swipes, implementing onScroll and/or onFling (probably both).  This might work okay if you want to scroll the view by one contiguous item per gesture.  You certainly could also implement continuous scrolling this way but I'd seriously consider whether this kind of interaction offers a good user experience.  Usually on a touch device, the user would not expect scrolling to work this way around.

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html